# Retrieving an element within a ToggleGroup

Tags: javafx, toggle

How can someone retrieve the element that was put into a toggle group? Or perhaps there is another way to organize controls so they can be toggled and clients are also able get the actual control from within the group?

What I have

```
RadioButton radio1 = new RadioButton();  
RadioButton radio12= new RadioButton();  
ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();  
radio1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
radio2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
```

What I want

```
RadioButton temp = toggleGroup.getSelectedObject();
```

Or

```
RadioButton temp = toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getObject();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want retrieve all toggle on the group:

```
toggleGroup.getToggles()
```

give you a list of all toggle.

if you want the selected toggle :

```
toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle()
```

give you a Toggle object.

So I think on this line `RadioButton temp = toggleGroup.getSelectedObject();` you have to cast   like that `RadioButton temp =(RadioButton) toggleGroup.getSelectedObject();`

Comment: Yes, I think that does it. Thanks